# Entity Framework 6.1.1 Insert Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I can't seem to find a suitable solution for my problem on SO or in tutorials.

I have the following code first schema (part of it anyways).

```
public partial class Csr
{
    public virtual CsrData CsrData { get; set; }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Id { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class CsrData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Csr Csr { get; set; }
}
```

I've also explicitly defined the relationship:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);          
    modelBuilder.Entity<Csr>().HasOptional(csr => csr.CsrData).WithRequired();
}
```

Both Ids are the same and I want to maintain a Csr 1 <-> 0..1 CsrData relationship. I believe this part is at the very least correct.

Now, I'm retrieving these objects from another source, and need to store it in the Db.

**When I try inserting:**

```
public void InsertCsr(Csr csr)
{
    var data = (EntityDataSource.DbContext as SmsData.SmsData);
    csr.CsrData.Csr = csr;

    data.Csrs.AddOrUpdate(csr);

    data.SaveChanges();

    EntityDataSource.Refresh();
}
```

CsrData doesn't get inserted. Csr will get inserted, and model changes will appear in CsrData table. Is EF supposed to persist inserts?

**Alternatively, I've tried this:**

```
public void InsertCsr(Csr csr)
{
    var data = (EntityDataSource.DbContext as SmsData.SmsData);
    csr.CsrData.Csr = csr;
    data.Csrs.AddOrUpdate(csr);
    data.CsrData.AddOrUpdate(csr.CsrData);
    data.SaveChanges();
    EntityDataSource.Refresh();
}
```

AddOrUpdate(csr.CsrData) throws a generic NullRefException from EntityFramework.dll with:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
_HResult=-2147467261
_message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
HResult=-2147467261
IsTransient=false
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
```

**Edit:**
I've figured out why CsrData wasn't inserting, because SQL Server default has a string length of 4000 chars, I've set it to max now and inserts are working.

Though as part of my original question, my full schema is such that Csr references (0..1) CsrData entry, and has a collection of another object.

To insert the Csr obj with all of its references I have to run:

```
data.CsrData.AddOrUpdate(csr.CsrData);
data.CsrTransactions.AddOrUpdate(csr.Transactions.ToArray());
data.Csrs.AddOrUpdate(csr);
```

Should EF be persisting my references if I AddOrUpdate just a Csr object?

Comment: What is `csr.CsrData.Csr = csr` supposed to do? And what do you mean by "model changes will appear in CsrData table" if CsrData is not inserted?

Comment: I've erased the line csr.CsrData.Csr = csr, it was a reference to the original object. I meant the table will change when I change the code first classes but won't insert. I've figured out why inserts don't work. SQL Server by default supports max 4k characters and it was throwing an error on length of entries which wasn't showing up in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved something similar by following this MSDN post http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToOptional

In CsrData class: change Id to CsrId (it helps identify the intent)

In OnModelCreating function: change the modelBuilder definition to

```
// Configure the primary key for the CsrData 
  modelBuilder.Entity<CsrData>().HasKey(t => t.CsrId); 

// Map one-to-zero or one relationship 
  modelBuilder.Entity<CsrData>() 
      .HasRequired(t => t.Csr) 
      .WithOptional(t => t.CsrData);
```

Also, I usually call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` last

Comment: Should I be using separate inserts for each table or the one on Csrs table?

Comment: Alright, the insert isn't failing, but when I double check with an SQL Server viewer I have nothing in the CsrData table.

Comment: This `csr.CsrData.Csr = csr;` doesn't look quite right.